# Contar cuantos registros hay en un rango de horas Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

necesito una ayuda!. Quisiera una consulta en el cual me muestre cuantos registros hay en un rango de horas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es mi tabla, lo que quiero es contar cuantos registros hay en un rango de horas. Por ejemplo en el resultado debería salir que hay un registro entre el rango de horas de 08:00:00 y 09:00:00.

Igual si es que pongo por ejemplo 08:30:00 y 09:00:00 y pertenece al rango, debería valer como un registro también

Eh probado esta consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as conteo FROM horario WHERE hinicio_paca between '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' AND hfin_paca between '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' AND dias_paca = '1' AND dnts_id = '2' OR ( hinicio_paca < '08:00:00' AND hfin_paca > '09:00:00') AND dias_paca = '1' AND dnts_id = '2'
```

dias_paca significa que día es el id de que día, 1 = lunes, 2 = martes, etc.
dnts_id es el id del maestro.

¡Espero se me entienda, es urgente! por favor gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hice esta consultla de aqui:

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as conteo FROM horario 
        WHERE hinicio_paca between '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' AND hfin_paca between '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' AND dias_paca = '1' AND dnts_id = '2'
        OR ( hinicio_paca < '08:00:00' AND hfin_paca > '09:00:00') AND dias_paca = '1' AND dnts_id = '2'

Comment: Aparte de que el planteamiento no es claro, tienes columnas redundantes en tu tabla. Toda la información que necesitas podría guardarse en dos columnas del tipo `DATETIME`, que se llamarían por ejemplo: `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_fin`, allí guardarías tanto la fecha, como la hora y luego si te interesa consultar por parte de la información (día, hora, mes) usarías las funciones propias para ello. No tiene sentido guardar datos de fecha en columnas separadas. Eso agranda la BD y complica las consultas posteriores, que es lo que sucede aquí. Aparte de aumentar la posibilidad de datos erróneos.

Comment: No se entiende el contexto del problema. Se todo lo especifico que puedas para poder ayudarte